# svnlook E720123 Can't open file '.....\local SVN repo\format'

Tags: svn

I created an SVN repo on local machine with windows system. I tried to use `svnlook`to make some test (for further development of svn hook) with following command but failed:

```
svnlook changed -r 12 "file://E:/SVN repos/local SVN repo"
```

The failed message is `"svnlook: E720123: Can't open file 'file:\E:\SVN repos\local SVN repo\format'`

In addition, I tried to use similar command with url got from svn repo-browser: `svnlook changed -r 12 "file:///E:/SVN%20repos/local%20SVN%20repo"`, but failed again with almost same message.

Could anyone help me with this problem? And why would there be a `/format` appended after given url in the message?

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer in the [SVN book](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svnlook/)

> Since svnlook works via direct repository access (and thus can be used only on the machine that holds the repository), it refers to the repository with a path, not a URL.

And problem solved after I use a direct path in command: `svnlook changed -r 12 "E:/SVN repos/local SVN repo"`.